# Reading in comma-separated values from file without using a loop?

Tags: python, csv

If each line of a text file looks something like this

```
Carlos Guestrin,CIS 41A,4.5,A,BUS 55,5,A,BUS 18,5,B+,HUMI 16,4,A-
```

How would I read all the data into a data structure without using a loop? I'm thinking of having the name (Carlos) be an instance variable and store only the values after the name into the data structure, namely a dictionary of tuples (with the class name as the key value)

Comment: Use the `csv` library to read the file.

Comment: It the number of fields variable, since students can take different numbers of classes?

Comment: The question is ambiguous. Do you want to read the file without using a loop or store the values without a loop or just no loops at all? Why do you want to do it without loops?

Comment: In addition to use `csv` library as @Barmar pointed out, you can also consider use `str,split(',')`. See: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: @spaniard I used that in my answer.

Comment: True, I am sorry @Barmar.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the csv library:

```
import csv
with open('file.csv') as f:
    data = list(csv.reader(f))
```

Data becomes a list of lists, with each list being a row in your file.

Edit:

To get this into a dict of tuples you can further process it with a dict comprehension:

```
data = {i[1]: {"Name": i[0], "Grades": tuple(i[1:])} for i in data}
```

If you're trying to get rid of the first row just slice data (`data = data[1:]`)

Comment: He seems to be looking for more structure than that, like grouping the class names and grades into tuples.

Comment: @Barmar noted and edited

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use a loop? If you can use a dictionary comprehension, you can do:

```
row = line.strip().split(',')
record = {"name": line[0], "grades": {row[i]: row[i+1]} for i in range(1, len(row), 2}}
```

You could also use a class instance instead of a dictionary.

Instead of calling `split()` explicitly, you can use the `csv` library as in @Primusa's answer to read each line into a list, then use the above dictionary comprehension to rearrange it into more structured form.

Answer (score 0):

You code use [`str.spltline()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) which would return a `list` of strings.

E.G.

```
from pprint import pprint

filename = 'test_data'
with open(filename, 'r') as inp:
    data = inp.read().splitlines()

pprint(data)
```

Sample output:

```
['Carlos Guestrin1,CIS 41A,4.5,A,BUS 55,5,A,BUS 18,5,B+,HUMI 16,4,A-',
 'Carlos Guestrin2,CIS 41A,4.5,A,BUS 55,5,A,BUS 18,5,B+,HUMI 16,4,A-',
 'Carlos Guestrin3,CIS 41A,4.5,A,BUS 55,5,A,BUS 18,5,B+,HUMI 16,4,A-']
```